# table is not filling up in xammp using php code

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

For the following code i am not getting expected output. i expect data from a table to be fetched and placed in a new table. Table `l3` contains `rollno`, `department`, `cgpa`.Table `l4` has to be filled with `rollno`, `department` ,`cgpa` after checking whether the required `cgpa` is specified.

```
<?php

include "new.php";

$cgpa = 4;

$sql = "SELECT ROLLNO, NAME, DEPARTMENT, CGPA FROM l3 WHERE CGPA >= '$cgpa'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO l4 (ROLLNO,NAME,DEPARTMENT,CGPA)VALUES({$row['ROLLNO']},{$row['NAME']},{$row['DEPARTMENT']},{$row['CGPA']})";
        mysqli_query($link, $sql2);
    }
}

else
    echo "No records found.";

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

the new.php has the following code

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Sreejith@12", "vig");

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else
    echo "connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: Check for sql errors. Specifically you are missing single quotes on string values.

Comment: [Here's some info on how to catch errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) from your `mysqli_query` function